# WMS GetMap request with POST and XML in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, xml, http-post

It's possible to make WFS queries by POSTing query as XML.

Does GeoServer support this also for WMS GetMap request? If yes, I'm looking for information on XML syntax for such query. Sounds like a "open documentation and start reading" question, but I haven't found any information.

It's possible to POST GetMap query with same syntax as regular GET queries have, but I'm looking for XML solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the GetCapabilities response of the GeoServer services to see if those services support XML/POST requests for GetMap requests.  For example in one GeoServer service I just looked at:

```
<GetMap>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
  <Format>application/atom+xml</Format>
  ...
  <DCPType>
    <HTTP>
      <Get>
        <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://xxx/geoserver/CPRM_EN_Bedrock_and_Age/ows?SERVICE=WMS&"/>
      </Get>
    </HTTP>
  </DCPType>
</GetMap>
```

Only **<Get>** support is listed.

I looked at a couple of GeoServer services and didn't see Post listed, so its possible that XML/POST support is not available in GeoServer as a default operation.

As your question is specifically about GeoServer I should probably stop there, but I can tell you that other FOSS4G WMS server software does support XML/POST operations for GetMap requests, for example [MapServer](http://www.mapserver.org/)

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer has been supporting XML GetMap for 13+ years, even if it does not advertise it in the capabilities document (pull requests welcomed!).
Some examples:

- http://www.how2map.com/2013/10/geoserver-getmap-with-http-post.html
- https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/data/release/demo/WMS_ge

tMap_inlineFeatureSmile.xml

However it is currently impossible to send SQL viewparams with this solution as it is not present in the [WMS GetMap specs](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1081&version=1&format=pdf).